# Mark and $80$ employees

Tags: statistics

The company at which Mark is employed has $80$ employees, each of whom has a different salary. Mark's salary of $ \$43,700 $ is the second-highest salary in the first quartile of the $80$ salaries. If the company were to hire $8$ new employees at salaries that are less than the lowest of the $80$ salaries, what would Marks' company be with respect to the quartiles of the $88$ salaries at the company, assuming no other changes in the salaries $?$

$A$) The fourth-highest salary in the first quartile

$B$) The highest salary in the first quartile

$C$) The second-lowest salary in the second quartile

$D$) The third-lowest salary in the second quartile

$E$) The fifth-lowest salary in the second quartile

---

I am not sure why the correct answer is $E$. I understand only that first quartile is the top $25\%$ of all the salaries.

Why does Mark's second-highest salary status suddenly change to the fifth-lowest salary just by adding $8$ new employees that are in the lowest of the $80$ salaries$?$

Comment: A change can only occur if first is not top but lowest quartile.

Answer (score 1):

"First quartile" means the lowest quartile. Please refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile).

Thus we know Mark is the 62th highest in salary. Since the new second quartile contains 45th to 66th highest in salary, he is the fifth lowest in the second quartile.